# Push Notification in .Net core 2.1 MVC with Azure MySQL as database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I am creating my website application in .net core 2.1. I have to deploy it in WebApp of Azure. Backend DB is Azure MySQL service.

Can i create SignalR with MySQL and show notification in my .net core MVC application?